# From binary to UTF-16 text and vice versa

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I would like to convert a hexedicimal binary to UTF-16

just like this converter in this website 
http://sms.24cro.com/op_1_4_en.htm

note: I am not reading the binary from a file, it is coming as query-string to my website

Example input:

```
06270646062700200627062d06280640064006400640064006400640064006400640064006400640064006400643
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [binary to UTF-16](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756992/binary-to-utf-16)

Comment: it is not duplicate , that one is already closed

Comment: Of course it was a duplicate! I have deleted it, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps here:

- converting a hexadecimal string into a `byte[]`
- converting a `byte[]` to a string

The second of these is trivial, for example:

```
byte[] blob = ...
string s = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(blob);
```

So how about the first? Each pair will be one byte, so:

```
byte[] blob = new byte[input.Length / 2];
```

For each pair, we need to convert a byte:

```
for(int i = 0; i < blob.Length ; i++) {
    string pair = input.Substring(2 * i, 2);
    blob[i] = Convert.ToByte(pair, 16); // from hex to byte
}
```

So putting that all together:

```
byte[] blob = new byte[input.Length / 2];
for(int i = 0; i < blob.Length ; i++) {
    string pair = input.Substring(2 * i, 2);
    blob[i] = Convert.ToByte(pair, 16); // from hex to byte
}
string s = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(blob);
```

Comment: thank you marc ,  i have tried the code you have post, result should be arabic (انا احبـــــــــــــــك) , but it is something else now(✆䘆✆ ✆ⴆ⠆䀆䀆䀆䀆䀆䀆䀆䀆䀆䀆䀆䀆䀆䀆䀆䌆)

Comment: @hamitay then you probably have the wrong encoding. Are you sure it is UTF-16? Also try Encoding.BigEndianUnicode - see what that gives, but: you need to know the exact encoding. Encoding.UTF8 and Encoding.UTF32 are worth a try, too.

Comment: Mark i love you, thank you very much  it is working now i t is   encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(blob);

Answer (score -1):

Please find the code for converting hexa to Arabic.

```
byte[] blob = new byte[text1.Text.Length / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < blob.Length; i++)
{
    string pair = text1.Text.Substring(2 * i, 2);
    blob[i] = Convert.ToByte(pair,16); // from hex to byte 
}
string s;//
s = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(blob);
Label3.Text = s;
```

Comment: [What's the problem with Marc answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9757341/792066)